# Angular 7 deployment on azure server

Tags: bash, azure, azure-web-app-service, angular7

I am a newbie to microsoft azure server ,I've created a basic app in angular 7 with nodeJS as backend language ,Now i want to deploy that app but i can't setup angular7 enivronment.
 i've tried to install angular cli via bash but its not working for me ,my npm version is 5.6.0 and nodejs version on azure cloud is 8.9.4
I get the following error [image: this error]

Comment: try running with sudo

Comment: I tried with sudo too but it still doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried running as administrator?